# A little red dot appears when using the anchor element HTML

Tags: html

I'm making a HTML website from scratch, and when I add an anchor element to a h2, to link to another page in the site, a purple dot/line appears, which turns red when you click the button 'Eligibility'. Also, the red/purple line is a link too, and can be clicked to go the 'Eligibility page'.

When I remove the `<a>` elements, it disappears, but of course then I can't link to another web-page.
Here's the code:
(Of course I have more code but it's private. I have a file in the same directory called 'eligibility.html')

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <h2 class='nav'>Home</h2>
    <a href='./eligibility.html'>
      <h2 class='nav'>Eligiblity</h2>
    </a>
    <h2 class='nav'>What we do</h2>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

The part of the site that I'm on about: The navigation buttons

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Links by default have styles such as a colour and an underline. You can add this css to remove all the link styles.

```
a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

It would be better to add a class to your button links so this style doesn't apply to all your links on your page though.

Comment: Is a:active for pages that you are currently on? Because I wouldn't want to disable that, lets say you _are_ on 'eligibility', the eligibility button would be a different colour, so the user knows he is on that page.

Comment: :active happens when you click on it, see here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active

Comment: @HarithShah I updated my answer to a more simplified version. The `active` is for when you hold down and press the link (so before you let go of it and it redirects you)